# how do I list all states (CustomerState) where there is at least one customer, Without repeating states?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I Just started sql and was wondering how I get a list of customers from at least one state with no duplicates This is what I have and it comes up but I do not believe that is exactly right especially From WHERE

```
SELECT Distinct Customerstate
FROM Customer_T
WHERE CustomerState
```

Comment: If Customer_T is a table in which all your customer information lies (such that a customer state would not exist there without a customer), then you need no `WHERE` clause. Just select the distinct states from that table. You _may_ want to filter out `NULL` if the customerstate column is nullable (`WHERE CustomerState IS NOT NULL`).

Comment: A query is a good start. Adding sample tables and desired results will help your readers understand your problems, resulting in faster answers and required explanations. Start here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve